# Bootstrap alert closing on page load

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-messages

I have a view in which I send some messages, like this:

```
messages.warning(request, 'Nothing found")
```

In my `settings.py` I have edited the message tags like:

```
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.DEBUG: 'alert-info',
    messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
    messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
    messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
    messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger'
}
```

on my template, I display them like this:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade in">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {% if message.tags == 'info' %}
            <p>{{ message }}<br>
                You have <strong>{{users}}</strong> user{{users|pluralize}}<br>
         ,around <strong>{{non_users}}</strong> non user{{non_users|pluralize}}</p>
        {% else %}
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When the template loads, the messages appears very fast and disappears.

If I try this: `<p>{{message}}</p>` instead the message stays there, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with bootstrap.

This (kinda) works as well: `<div class="{{message.tags}}">`

Could someone shed a light?

**Edit:**

I just noticed this is happening specifically when I use `messages.error()`, the rest of them are working properly, can't seem to find what's wrong.

Comment: Do you want to destroy the message when clicking on the close button?

Comment: Yeah, it should be doing that already, but it seems like the `alert` class is breaking something.

Answer (score 0):

try this, the class is `alert-{{tag}}` which will render `alert-info`, there's no whitespace

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}} page-alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss='alert'>
             <span aria-hidden="true"> × </span>
             <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <p>{{message}}</p> 
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: my message tags are already formatted to display it like that

Comment: so, what's exactly the issue?

Comment: It seems like that `alert` class is triggering something that closes the div. I have no js code that does that tho.

Comment: do you have it that way `alert alert-{{message.tags}}` instead of `alert {{message.tags}}`?

Comment: It should be displayed like `alert {{message.tags}}` which translates to `alert alert-warning`

Comment: Try removing these `class` : `alert-dismissible fade in`

Comment: Wouldn't that make it non-closable?

Comment: Of course, but add it to the button instead... `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss='alert'`